# If "so that, in order that, in case, for fear (that),lest" introduce adverbial clause of purpose

Tags: word-usage, subjunctives

If "so that, in order that,  in case, for fear (that), lest" introduce adverbial clause of purpose, should we use  'subjunctive' clauses?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Subjunctive is usually avoided in English, but still good question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly could, in certain contexts--"Don't make too much noise, lest he wake!" is a spontaneous example--but this has kind of an archaic feel to it.

English subjunctive isn't really used too much any more, and it's likely to seem unusual to many audiences. So while you could say "We moved very quietly, for fear that he wake", it would sound more typical to say "We moved very quietly, for fear of waking him".